# Нельзя выбрать диск, как каталог в Filechooser

Tags: файлы

Filechooser позволяет выбрать каталог и далее открывать папки или файлы в нем вложенные. Затруднение в том, что я не могу указать таким способом диск, так как он не считается каталогом.

Comment: Используй JavaFX http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm

Answer (score 0):

## попробуйте так обратиться C:\

\ - корневой каталог